# Entity Framework error - nested model problem

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC and want to create a small order management tool. My database contains the tables Orders and Articles (and a few other ones), and I generated an EF Model from my database, so I can use the full power of the EF mappings (e.g. db.Orders.Articles)

My two main relations which I'm concerned about are Orders and Articles.

- An order can have many articles
- An article can only belong to one order.

I've created an OrdersController with an Create action to create an order:

```
        //
    // GET: /Orders/Create

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        Order order = new Order()
        {
           // filling some order columns, e.g. date
        };

        Article article = new Article()
        {
            // ... article columns
        };

        order.Articles.Add(article);

        return View(order);

    } 

    //
    // POST: /Orders/Create

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Order order)
    {
        // i know i should care more about error handling, but now ommit it
        db.Orders.AddObject(order);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("index");
    }
```

So I'm directly binding an EF Object to a view (read somewhere not to do that and use a view model instead, but don't really know what that view model should look like)

My view contains the Order form as well as the article form (because i want to create a order and articles at the same time and not seperate). I used these greate EditorFor Methods to do that.

And now to my problem: If i hit the submit button, the app crashes as soon as it comes to the HttpPost Create Method (when mapping the order) with this error message:

> Error Message: The EntityCollection
>   has already been initialized. The
>   InitializeRelatedCollection method
>   should only be called to initialize a
>   new EntityCollection during
>   deserialization of an object graph.

If i hit continue in VS2010, it will complete saving the order - so my question is how to solve this problem in a reliable way.

Thanks in advance and sorry for that long story :)

Comment: My advice would be to not use the EF object as your model and to create a `ViewModel` instead (as you mention in your question). The `ViewModel` should contain all the fields you are going to show/edit in the view, so initially you might just create a copy of your entity objects and name them `OrderViewModel` and `ArticleViewModel` and the `OrderViewModel` will contain a list of `ArticleViewModels`. In the `Create` action you just have to make sure you copy all the data from the viewmodels into the EF objects (this process can be automated - take a look at Automapper).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem now by using a separate ViewModel like @Yakimych advised me. However I did not copy all the attributes from the EF models, instead I just refer to them. My ViewModel looks like this:

```
public class NewOrderViewModel {
  public Order { get; set; }
  public List<Article> { get; set; }
}
```